# How to split same record in Form Grid?

Tags: forms, grid, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I need to split the same record two time.
For example, if I have in MyTable *five* record I need to show in *Form's Grid* *ten* record.

If It's possible I can create a *View*, I just to duplicate one time the same record.

This is my start point : [image: StartPoint No Repeat record]

I want to duplicate the record : [image: Duplicate Record]

**In MyForm can't edit anything, is only View. No Delete, No Edit, No Create**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain your purpose?

Comment: Thanks @Aliaksandr Maksimau, I have not explained well .I add more info in my question. If you need ask-me, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an exercise, which we probably shouldn't be giving you the answer to...but try creating `MyTableJoin` and create a foreign key relation to `MyTable.Id` then add a field called `MyTableJoin.Row` and populate the table with 2 matching rows for every 1 row in `MyTable`.  Then on your form, join `MyTableJoin`.

So:

```
MyTableJoin.clear();
MyTableJoin.Id = "ID_I";
MyTableJoin.Row = 1;
MyTableJoin.insert();

MyTableJoin.clear();
MyTableJoin.Id = "ID_I";
MyTableJoin.Row = 2;
MyTableJoin.insert();

MyTableJoin.clear();
MyTableJoin.Id = "ID_II";
MyTableJoin.Row = 1;
MyTableJoin.insert();

MyTableJoin.clear();
MyTableJoin.Id = "ID_II";
MyTableJoin.Row = 2;
MyTableJoin.insert();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a union view and add same table twice. Just be shore to select union all option so that you do not get unique results.